# Firebase offline functionality on ionic android app

Tags: android, angularjs, firebase, offline-caching

I am a computing student and I have a college project that I'm working on and it has to do with ionic framework. It is an ionic android app that uses Firebase as a backend - consumes data from firebase. Now I want to add offline functionality to my app so that the users can still access most of the app features as they are offline. I was wondering if there any tutorials that I can follow to integrate the offline functionality to my app please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You Can use localforage for offline functionality.find more details on the following link
https://github.com/mozilla/localForage

Comment: I hope this helped you